# How to include a post type in the admin/backend?

Tags: posts, include, customization

I'm changing the backend/admin and want to show a div above the pages.
How can I include the pages like the example;

[image: example]

```
<?php
include('./tools.php') ;
```

this works but when I choose edit.php / edit.php?post_type=page it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First...

> I'm changing the backend/admin ...

Your description makes it sound like you are hacking Core. Don't do that. It is a maintenance nightmare.

The action hook [`in_admin_header`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-admin/admin-header.php#L195) looks to be placed about where you want to put your content.

```
190 /**
191  * Fires at the beginning of the content section in an admin page.
192  *
193  * @since 3.0.0
194  */
195 do_action( 'in_admin_header' );
```

Use that hook to add your content.

```
function admin_content_wpse_144936() {
  echo 'howdy';
}
add_action('in_admin_header','admin_content_wpse_144936');
```

If you look at the 75 lines or so below that hook in the source you will see several other hooks that might be promising as well.

The `admin_head-$hook_suffix` hook could be used to give you pretty good control over when your content is added. For example:

```
function admin_content_wpse_144936() {
  echo 'howdy';
}

function add_admin_content_wpse_144936() {
  add_action('in_admin_header','admin_content_wpse_144936');
}
add_action('admin_head-edit.php','add_admin_content_wpse_144936');
```